# Whats wrong with my log4net configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I have an ASP.NET MVC app which has a bootstrapper class that configures log4net during application startup as follows:

```
public static void Configure(IApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    var appender = new log4net.Appender.FileAppender
    {
        Layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%d [%t]%-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n"),
        File = applicationContext.GetLogFile().FullName
    };

    BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
}
```

I have checked that when I call the logging function later that the repository is configured:

```
LogManager.GetRepository().Configured
```

this returns true.

The location of `applicationContext.GetLogFile().FullName` exists and also has permissions set for any user to be able to create and modify files, so I don't quite understand why this fails to create a log file or output any data.

Now I know you can use config files and XML in the Web.config but because the log file location and configuration will change from site to site I need to do this in code.

Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add an

```
appender.ActivateOptions();
```

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know the answer to my next query would you?